# Switching deploy servers on Bluemix

Tags: deployment, ibm-cloud, blue-green-deployment

I am not quite sure how to name this question. But, I will list the expectations below to explain it.

- Having an application running on Bluemix.
- Having code on local.
- Push through git to Bluemix.
- Restart the application for new code to take effect.

So the question is: 
In the above situation, if I want to avoid down time while the server is restarting, which could be long if it is having unexpected issues, how can the website keep transferring data through the Bluemix server. Should I have a shadow server? How do I manage them so they know when to switch (automatic/manual) in case the website won't notice the down time? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a blue green deployment.  Here is an example article http://garage.mybluemix.net/posts/blue-green-deployment/